# Configuring Impala with LDAP

Tags: hadoop, impala

I'm using CDH 4.5. I installed Impala manually (without Cloudera Manager). I've configured LDAP with Impala (using the instructions at http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/Impala/latest/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_ldap.html).

I've added ldap_uri to the /etc/default/impala file. But how do I configure the ldap bind username?

With the current configuration, if I start impala shell, I am able to login using the ldap bind username. But how do I login using actual users from AD? I need to configure the ldap bind username and / or ldap password so that impala automatically connects using the bind username and when I start the impala shell, I can connect using actual user names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently we don't have to use the ldap bind name. I'm able to log in with user name as "someone@abc.com" where someone is the user name in AD and abc.com is the AD search base.